# Unable to RDP from Windows 10 to Debian 10

Tags: debian, rdp, xrdp

I have a Vultr VPS running Debian 10. It's a newly created instance with no firewall. I have installed `xfce` and `xrdp` but I am unable to connect to this machine from Windows 10 PC via RDP.

First I installed xfce:
`apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies xorg dbus-x11 x11-xserver-utils`

Then I installed xrdp:
`apt install xrdp`

Checking xrdp status shows:

```
root@vultr:~# systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-09-07 10:36:13 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 2112 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2120 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2121 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1137)
   Memory: 1020.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─2121 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Sep 07 10:36:12 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Sep 07 10:36:12 vultr.guest xrdp[2120]: (2120)(140273561200448)[DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
Sep 07 10:36:12 vultr.guest xrdp[2120]: (2120)(140273561200448)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
Sep 07 10:36:12 vultr.guest systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Sep 07 10:36:13 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
Sep 07 10:36:14 vultr.guest xrdp[2121]: (2121)(140273561200448)[INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 2121
Sep 07 10:36:14 vultr.guest xrdp[2121]: (2121)(140273561200448)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
```

And after that when I connect from Windows 10 then I get error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's the Windows firewall? Is the debian machine reachable via ping or telnet?

Comment: Windows firewall should not be a problem because I am able to connect to other RDPs. I destroyed that VPS and installed a new one with Ubuntu and there the RDP is working but now I am facing another problem i.e. once I connect to RDP and enter user/password, it just disconnects after like 2, 3 seconds.

Comment: Regarding that disconnection after login, that issue is also solved because I was using root which is by default not allowed to login via xrdp. I created a new user and now I can connect to xrdp just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with Debian but I created another VPS using Ubuntu and when I installed GNOME desktop and xrdp then it worked fine.